Perturbation theory of spectral gap at specific point in spectrum
Suppose I have a family of finite system-size $N$ Hamiltonians $H^{(N)}$ (i.e. hermitian matrices of dimension $2^N\times2^N$). I know that for a certain scalar $E^{(N)}$ $(H^{(N)} - E^{(N)})^2$ has spectral gap of size $\mathcal{O}(1)$ (i.e. independent of system size).
Now I wonder about a perturbation $(H^{(N)} + g H_1^{(N)}- E^{(N)})^2$ where $g$ is small. I would expect there to be some statement, that the spectral gap of this new Hamiltonian is lower bounded by something with asymptotic scaling in $N$, if $g \ll$ than something with asymptotic scaling in $N$ as well as some operator norm on $H_1$.
I have been told this should be easily provable in perturbation theory, and I have been trying to piece this together with 'Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators' by Tosio Kato, however have not managed to do so. So I am wondering, is the above true and what statements from perturbation theory would be needed to prove this?

Just a, possibly naive guess, but have you tried to play around with Weyl's inequalities yet?

This was one thing I looked at, but I did not try hard enough - indeed a proof of the form mentioned in the question does go through with Weyl's inequalities, though I had to use additional properties of the specific $H^{(N)}_1$ and $E^{(N)}$ I am using. Thanks!

If you've found an answer, consider to write up an answer. It might be (very) useful and interesting for potential future readers.

Will do! Also happy to accept if you post an answer of yours mentioning the Weyl inequalitites, was very helpful to be pointed in this direction again!

Okay, nice. Glad I could help. Unfortunately I don't have much time right now.
